# Sending command from bash in shell-mode, and knowing buffer name

Tags: mode-line, shell-mode

My specific goal is setting `'vc-mode` from the $PROMPT1 snippet so that the mode line will show useful VC info in shell-mode.

I can use `emacsclient -e '(setq vc-mode "foo")'` but that's not quite enough since `'vc-mode` needs to be a buffer local variable, and so I will first need to pass the name of the `shell-mode` buffer into bash somehow.

Is there a known pattern for doing this kind of thing?

Comment: You could write a shell function asking Emacs which buffer corresponds to the process with pid `$$`.

Comment: You don't need to pass the name of the buffer to bash: `emacsclient -e "(with-current-buffer (process-buffer (cl-find $$ (process-list) :test (lambda (pid pr) (eq pid (process-id pr))))) (setq vc-mode \"foo\"))"`

Comment: One comment more related to the question itself: The biggest difficulties with running shell commands in a comint-buffer from elisp are related to the asynchronous execution of the shell. When executing commands one needs to take care of pending output. But, setting environment-variables of the shell does not require capturing of the output. So `(comint-send-string (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)) (concat "EMACS_BUFFER=" (buffer-name)))` should essentially work. One has to advice `rename-buffer` such that `EMACS_BUFFER` is kept current. Alternatively set `EMACS_BUFFER` before use.